# Consulta informação de um Tabsheet relacionado ao TListView

Tags: delphi, listview

Bem sou iniciante e estou com um grande problema.

Estou com a seguinte situação:

Eu crio um item no `Tlistview` ao dar dois cliques no item selecionado adiciono um objeto no caso o `form` ao item do `listview` e crio um `form` com `parent` ao `Tabsheet`.

No caso o que não estou conseguindo é relacionar o `Tabsheet` ao item quando eu for fechar o `form` ou deleta o item. Consegui fazer apenas adicionando o `handle` do `Tabsheet` ao  item selecionado, faço o *loop* da `handle` para identificar qual `tabsheet` esta relacionado ao item.

No `ondblclick` do `listview`:

```
LV1.Selected.SubItems[1]:=IntToStr(NewTabSheet.Handle);
LV1.Selected.SubItems.Objects[3] := TObject(NewTabSheet);
```

No `onChange` do `PageControl` eu tento identificar o `tabsheet`:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.pgc1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  i, c: integer;
begin
  try
    for i := 0 to lv1.Items.Count -1 do
      if i > 0 then
      begin
        if IntToStr(pgc1.ActivePage.Handle) = Form1.lv1.Items.Item[i].SubItems[1] then
        begin
          lv1.Items.Item[i].Selected:= True;
          Abort;
        end;
      end;
   // ...
```

Aqui é quando tento setar alguma informação do item quando eu troco de `tabsheet`:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.SENDTEXT(txt:string;NUM:INTEGER);
var
  i,c:integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Form1.LV1.Items.count - 1 do
  begin
    if form1.lv1.Items[i].SubItems[1] = inttostr(pgc1.ActivePage.Handle) then
    begin
      (form1.lv1.Items[i].SubItems.Objects[2]as TForm2).StatusText.Panels[NUM].Text:=txt;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Me corrijam porque eu estou me perdendo no código, creio que meu método esteja errado!

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54277/discussion-on-question-by-mrhelp-consulta-informacao-de-um-tabsheet-relacionado)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

1. Declare a função abaixo para identificar o `Form2` a partir do `PageControl`:

   ```
   function IdentificarFormulario(PageControl: TPageControl): TForm2;
   var
     tab: TTabSheet;
     I: Integer;
   begin
     Result := nil;
     tab := PageControl.ActivePage;
     for I := 0 to tab.ControlCount- 1 do
       if tab.Controls[I] is TForm then
       begin
         Result := TForm2(tab.Controls[I]);
         Break;
       end;
   end;
   ```
2. No evento `OnDblClick` do `Listview`, verifique se há algum item selecionado antes de atribuir informações ao `Listview`:

   ```
   // Se não houver nada selecionado, o código abaixo não será executado
   if LV1.Selected = nil then exit;

   LV1.Selected.SubItems[1] := IntToStr(NewTabSheet.Handle);

   // Onde "PGC1" é o componente "PageControl"
   LV1.Selected.SubItems.Objects[3] := IdentificarFormulario(PGC1);
   ```
3. Modifique a tua função `SENDTEXT` para que fique assim:

   ```
   procedure SENDTEXT(txt: string; NUM: INTEGER);
   var
     I: integer;
   begin
     for I := 0 to LV1.Items.Count - 1 do
       if (LV1.Items.Item[I] <> nil) and
          (LV1.Items.Item[I].SubItems[1] = IntToStr(pgc1.ActivePage.Handle))
       then
         TForm2(LV1.Items.Item[I].SubItems.Objects[3]).StatusText.Panels[0].Text := txt;
   end;
   ```
4. No evento `onChange` do `PageControl`, todo aquele código é desnecessário (*eu acho*), basta você chamar a função `SENDTEXT`:

   ```
   // Onde "texto" é a informação que você quer mostrar no "StatusText" do "Form2"
   // O segundo argumento é índice do "Panel" do "StatusText"
   SENDTEXT('Texto', 0);
   ```

Comment: demoro mais saiu kkkk msm coisa , vlw flw !!